# How to view detailed data of a specific list view item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Let's say i have a list of cities from a country.
If the user clicks one of them, i want a new screen to be displayed, with the detailed infos for that list element.
Also, that screen will have others buttons ( eg: Write Review, Post Picture )

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Seems lika a simple implementation of a [listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: I thought a little bit harder, and i think i will store a selected city object in my application subclass, and when i will start a new intent on click, that activity will use the data from the objected stored in my application subclass.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `City` class should implement `Parcelable`. Its `toString()` method should return the name of the city. (Rather than simply having the city as a `String`.)

When you populate your ListView, use an `ArrayAdapter<City>` instead of an `ArrayAdapter<String>` (this code assumes that the cities are kept in `List<City> list`):

```
City[] cities = new City[list.size()];
list.toArray(cities);
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.citylist);
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<City>(this,
    R.layout.listitem, cities));
```

In your onItemClick handler, get the selected city and add it as an extra on the intent you use to launch your details activity:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
            View v, int position, long id) {
        City city = (City) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.cities.City", city);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In your details activity, get the city from the extras on the intent:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
City city = bundle.getParcelable("com.example.cities.City");
```

Comment: @David What is better option for detailview? `FragmentActivity` or `Activity` or `fragment in Activity`?

Comment: @Roon13 Sorry, I don't know.